# cloud 9 c9 cli open fails

Tags: bash, cloud9-ide

Trying to open a file from a bash script in c9

```
c9 open README.md
```

does nothing, it does not show an error or open the file, is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version are you running? In the version currently online at c9.io this feature is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks, I am referring to the hosted, environment on c9.io. , the c9 command is there so I did not know if it would work. thanks.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. On the "v3" version of Cloud9, this is not supported. There may still be some legacy v2 versions floating around on the internet that have a feature like this, but the online service at c9.io doesn't yet reimplement this.